# jQuery / AngularJS - Upload file with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

Somebody can answer please, **once and for all**, if is it **possible** to **upload files using AJAX**?

I read a few posts on the web that stating that **file upload using AJAX** is **impossible**!

If it is possible, can somebody please provide a **working** piece of code of AJAX request?

I already tried about **10 examples** which I found on the web and no one is working.

Please do not refer me to plugins. I would like to understand how it works and implement it myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the following link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<input id="pic "type="file" name="file" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">
```

**JS:**

```
$("#pic").change(function() {
    var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data)
    alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(dat){
                    alert('it works maybe');
                }
     });
});
```